# REST call to ip does not work, but localhost works

Tags: java, rest, postman, grizzly

i have a implemented a http server (glassfish grizzly) in java.

If i submit a REST GET to localhost:3000/api/... i receive my response as expected.

If i sumbit that REST GET with my ip (192.168.0.100:3000/api...) i'm getting a "no reponse error".

Exactly the same behaviour when i start that java application on a different computer (192.168.0.200) in the same network. A GET request to 192.168.0.100:3000/api... also leads to the "no response error".

Am i missing something?

Comment: check your ip address

Comment: make sure glassfish  server is configured with your IP address `192.168.0.100`, not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure GlassFish to use the correct HTTP listener.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4495/ggnfu/index.html

> For example, an HTTP listener can listen on all configured IP addresses on a given port for a host by specifying the IP address 0.0.0.0. Alternatively, the HTTP listener can specify a unique IP address for each listener while using the same port.

Either define a listener on address `0.0.0.0` to listen on all addresses of the host, or be more specific and tell it to only listen on address `192.168.0.100`.

Comment: Thanks, adding a network listener solved that problem!

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are facing is cors restriction.: Ensure that your API server is configured to allow requests from the domain or IP address you are using. If CORS is not properly configured, the browser may block requests from different origins. you can also download allow cors extensions  from chrome web store. thanks